# How to change permissions on ExFAT filesystem?

Tags: macos, external-disk, exfat

I'm aware that ExFAT has no support for permissions and ownership and that I may have change the mount options to change the permissions, but I'm not sure how to do this. I just want to change the `chmod` permissions from `777` to `644`.

For more context, it's my external hard drive that is formatted to ExFAT and whenever I copy files from it the permissions are `777`. Then I'd have to manually change the permissions.

Edit: My question basically is: How can I set the mount options for external hard drives such that the permissions are set to 644 (so that I don’t have to manually change these when I copy files)?

Comment: Does `man mount_exfat` help?

Comment: I'm still new to the command line also, so I'll have to look for examples. I'm just worried that I might change something unexpectedly.

Comment: ExFAT just has no clue what 644 perms means. It doesn't have perms limited by owner/group/everyone, so everything will appear to be 777. See https://superuser.com/questions/468291/chmoding-file-on-exfat